# Dolphin file manager shows nothing under artist and album columns

Tags: linux-mint, dolphin

I am not sure if this can be fixed. The title and artist data are absent under Dolphin columns, while data is present in the info panel that can be enabled to the right (<kbd>F11</kbd>).

[image]

I am using Linux Mint 18 KDE, Dolphin 15.12.3.