# Replace file name with title in multiple audio files

Tags: audio, filenames, tagging

I want a CLI or GUI solution for replacing file name of each file with the title of that file.

I have multiple radio podcasts with file names that do not properly show the content. That is visible in media players under Title, but I have [problems seeing those in file mangers](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/324694/32012), so I want to replace file names with titles.

**I am looking for a Linux native tool**, while I know how to do this in Wine with programs like Foobar2000.

**Edit after comment**: these are mp3 files. I can see the title data displayed in the info panel of Dolphin file manager.

Comment: What format are the files in? “Title” is not a universal property of a file, it depends on the file format.

Comment: @Gilles - I will add that in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for a *native tool* there is the command line `mp3rename` available with some distributions, and the gui `pyrenamer`.

For the former, first set up a format of "title" (`&t`) with

```
mp3rename -s '&t'
```

then you can rename your files by just running `mp3rename` on them by
just giving it a list of filenames. E.g. if you are in a directory with mp3 files you type `mp3rename *.mp3`. Or you can recursively search for files named `*.mp3` from some starting directory ABC with e.g.

```
find ABC -name '*.mp3' -exec mp3rename {} \;
```

You might want to work on a copy of your files to ensure you have no surprises!

For the gui [pyrenamer](http://helpdeskgeek.com/linux-tips/batch-rename-files-photos-music-in-linux-with-pyrenamer/), later versions have a tab `Music` where you "rename music using its metadata". Put the string `{title}.mp3` in this field, select the files to operate on, and click `Preview` to see what the names would become.

[image]

Comment: how do you "run mp3rename on them"?

Comment: you just have to give it a list of filenames,  I updated my answer. Please work on a copy of your files!

Answer (score 1):

How about Perl? It's native to Linux. My test setup is as follows... `mp3.pl` script is in the same directory as the `music` directory which contains the songs we'll be working on. I pass this in as a command line argument. The code iterates over this directory, fetching all mp3 files. It then iterates over the list of tracks, and one at a time, renames them to the track title:

First, see what tracks we have:

```
$ ls music
track1.mp3  track2.mp3
```

The code:

```
use warnings;
use strict;

use File::Copy;
use File::Find::Rule;
use MP3::Tag;

if (! @ARGV){
    print "usage: perl mp3.pl <directory>\n";
    exit;
}

my $dir = $ARGV[0];

my @files = File::Find::Rule->file()
                            ->name('*.mp3')
                            ->in($dir);

for my $track (@files){
    my $mp3 = MP3::Tag->new($track);

    my $title = $mp3->title;
    $title .= '.mp3';

    move $track, "$dir/$title" or die $!;
}
```

Run it:

```
perl mp3.pl music
```

The 'music' directory after the change:

```
$ ls music/
Almost Famous.mp3  No Love (feat Lil Wayne).mp3
```